# JMenuItem overlapping with mnemonic in exe

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, jmenuitem, launch4j

I'm using Netbeans 7.0.1. I have the problem that JMenuItems and their mnemonics seem crammed.

On running, the JMenuItem and the mnemonic are spaced normally. After creating an .exe using [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net) the mnemonics overlap the JMenuItem.

Here's the screenshot:

[image: File]  [image: Edit]  [image: About]

Only the `setAccelerator()` function has suffered this disfiguration. `DefaultEditorKit.action` in the Edit menu looks alright or maybe it's because of the checkbox.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after a bit of research. It was a bug in java versions 5.0 & 6 ([Bug ID: JDK-6385366](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6385366)). It was resolved in version 6(b80). I used launch4j and Inno Setup to bundle jre6. Bundling the jar with a later version fixed the issue. [jre8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) works swimmingly.